# How to make the pivot point to stay twice of height?

Tags: python, pivot, maya

I’m new to Python programming in Maya.

I’m trying to make my first simple code that creates `polyCone` and move the pivot point to the tip and rotate the cone x-axis by 180 degrees.

How can I make pivot point to stay always twice of the height whenever I change the height value? In my code so far, I have to change the pivot point value with the height whenever I change the height.

Here is my code so far.

```
from maya import cmds
cmds.polyCone(r=1 h=3.8 sx=6)
cmds.move(0, 1.9, 0, “pCone1.scalePivot”, “pCone1.rotatePivot”, absolute = True)
```

Comment: You can set Maya to echo every command (also those performed by mouse actions) to the console. If you know how to do this with a mouse, let it echo those actions to the console.

Answer (score 1):

To make a pivot to stay always twice of the height whenever you change the height value, try to code like this:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

hght=4
cmds.polyCone(r=1,h=hght,sx=6)
cmds.move(0,2,0)
cmds.xform("pCone1",ws=True,piv=(0,hght*2,0))

# cmds.xform("pCone1",ws=True,rp=(0,2,0),sp=(0,0,0))
```